# Get value from one class and use it in another class in php

Tags: php

possibly this question could be repeated, but I googled it and did not found the exact question..

I have created two php files dll.php and bll.php.

**dll.php:**

```
<?php
    class mysql_helper
    {
        function testFunction()
        {
            echo "test Function executed";      
        }
    }
?>
```

**bll.php:**

```
<?php
    include('dll.php');

    class first
    {
        function first()
        {
            $dblayer = new mysql_helper();
            echo  $dblayer->testFunction(); 
        }   
        echo first();
    }
?>
```

What I am trying to do that, is to print **returned value** from **mysql_helper** class which is defined in dll.php.

I tried one thing, is that I changed my second php file'c code (bll.php) as below and it worked.

```
<?php
    include('dll.php');

    function first()
    {
        $dblayer = new mysql_helper();
        echo  $dblayer->testFunction(); 
    }   
    echo first();
?>
```

can anyone help me to identify the issue in code please..

Comment: You can't just place a random `echo first();` inside of a class.

Comment: I am new to php can you send me sample code?

Comment: I gave you code and solution in my answer

Comment: That's the wrong way of calling a method. First create an instance of class `first`, and then call its method.

Comment: If you are new to php try to find a decent IDE (eclipse, netbeans, phpstorm etc.). It will hint you to such simple errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` do not return value. `echo` just displays value. if you want return value you must use `return`.

```
<?php
    class mysql_helper
    {
        function testFunction()
        {
            return "test Function executed"; //return value      
        }
    }
?>
```

You also can not call function inside class body. You must first create object of that class and then call method:

```
<?php
    include('dll.php');

    class first
    {
        function first()
        {
            $dblayer = new mysql_helper();
            return $dblayer->testFunction(); //also return value
        }   

    }

    $first = new first();
    echo $first->first(); //now you can make echo
?>
```